# Cakephp 3 bin/cake bake - Undefined variable: argv

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've used Cakephp 2.x in earlier times and now I want to get in touch with the new Version 3.0.0

I installed Cakephp over composer, all worked fine. I've changed the Salt and configured database settings.

When trying to run bin/cake I'm getting the following error:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v3.0.0 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /html/APP/myapp/src/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

* app:  src
* root: /html/APP/myapp
* core: /html/APP/myapp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp

Available Shells:

[Migrations] migrations

[CORE] i18n, orm_cache, plugin, server

[app] console

To run an app or core command, type `cake shell_name [args]`
To run a plugin command, type `cake Plugin.shell_name [args]`
To get help on a specific command, type `cake shell_name --help`

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.5
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<pre class="cake-error"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr551ffb72d6447-trace').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr551ffb72d6447-trace').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');"><b>Notice</b> (8)</a>: Undefined variable: argv [<b>ROOT/bin/cake.php</b>, line <b>19</b>]<div     id="cakeErr551ffb72d6447-trace" class="cake-stack-trace" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr551ffb72d6447-code').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr551ffb72d6447-code').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Code</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);"     onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr551ffb72d6447-context').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr551ffb72d6447-context').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Context</a><pre id="</span></span></code>code" class="cake-code-dump" style="display: none;"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color:     #0000BB">&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">*/
<span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB"></span><span style="color: #007700">include&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">dirname</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">__DIR__</span><span sty</span></span></code></span>&nbsp;</span><span     style="color: #DD0000">'/config/bootstrap.php'</span><span style="color: #007700">;
</span></span></code></pre><pre id="cakeErr551ffb72d6447-context" class="cake-context" style="display: none;">$_GET = [
    &#039;/html/APP/myapp/bin/cake_php&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
    &#039;bake&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;
]
$_POST = []
$_COOKIE = []
$_FILES = []
$_SERVER = [
    &#039;SHELL&#039; =&gt; &#039;/bin/bash&#039;,
    &#039;TERM&#039; =&gt; &#039;linux&#039;,
    &#039;SSH_CLIENT&#039; =&gt; &#039;213.188.119.235 53953 22&#039;,
    &#039;SSH_TTY&#039; =&gt; &#039;/dev/pts/1&#039;,
    &#039;LC_ALL&#039; =&gt; &#039;de_DE.utf8&#039;,
    &#039;USER&#039; =&gt; &#039;p252938&#039;,
    &#039;PATH&#039; =&gt; &#039;/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/html/APP/lib/Cake/Console&#039;,
    &#039;MAIL&#039; =&gt; &#039;/var/mail/p252938&#039;,
    &#039;PWD&#039; =&gt; &#039;/html/APP/myapp&#039;,
    &#039;EDITOR&#039; =&gt; &#039;vi&#039;,
    &#039;LANG&#039; =&gt; &#039;de_DE.utf8&#039;,
    &#039;HOME&#039; =&gt; &#039;/home/www/p252938/./&#039;,
    &#039;SHLVL&#039; =&gt; &#039;1&#039;,
    &#039;LOGNAME&#039; =&gt; &#039;p252938&#039;,
    &#039;SSH_CONNECTION&#039; =&gt; &#039;213.188.119.235 53953 172.16.39.19 22&#039;,
    &#039;PHP_SELF&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
    &#039;REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT&#039; =&gt; (float) 1428159346.8385,
    &#039;REQUEST_TIME&#039; =&gt; (int) 1428159346
]
$_ENV = []
$isCli = false</pre><pre class="stack-trace">[main] - ROOT/bin/cake.php, line 19</pre></div></pre>
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Check the [`register_argc_argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) option in your CLI `php.ini`.

Comment: okay, now I'm getting: Error: Shell class for "Bake" could not be found.

Comment: I've tried https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5459 with composer require cakephp/bake=dev-master but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

AS @ndm mentioned: setting register_argc_argv to On solved the Problem. But than I got Shell Class for "Bake" could not be found. Adding

```
Plugin::load('Bake');
```

to boostrap.php helped

Comment: Normally that shouldn't be neccessary, as it's already being loaded in the `config/bootstrap_cli.php`, which should be [**included on the CLI**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.0.0/config/bootstrap.php#L111-L114). Check what `php_sapi_name()` returns on the CLI, if it isn't `cli`, then there's more wrong with your setup.

Comment: hi Stephan i have the same problem like you. can you help me to solve my error.

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't get notified... Did you solve your problem?