# Cakephp script running fine from command line but not from cron

Tags: php, cakephp, cron, command-line-interface, cakephp-2.0

Before anything I'll say that I've done extensive research online and the **offered solutions haven't worked for me**. For example I've tried everything posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259638/cakephp-shell-script-wont-run-as-cron-job) (including the linked solutions from there). This is probably due to the **uniqueness of my CakePHP installation** that I explain below.

My problem is that I have a Cakephp Shell script that when I run from the Command line works fine, for example:

```
Console/cake enrolmentlogs update_daily_enrolment_logs
```

However, when I call that script from cron I get an error. Cron call:

```
cd /path/to/app/ && Console/cake enrolmentlogs update_daily_enrolment_logs >> /path/to/app/webroot/cron_shell_logs.txt 2>&1
```

Error I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: argv in /path/to/app/Console/cake.php on line 48
Error: This file has been loaded incorrectly and cannot continue.
Please make sure that /lib/Cake/Console is in your system path,
and check the cookbook for the correct usage of this command.
(https://book.cakephp.org/)
#0 /path/to/libs/cakephp-2.10.18/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(54): ShellDispatcher->_initEnvironment()
#1 /path/to/libs/cakephp-2.10.18/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(65): ShellDispatcher->__construct(NULL)
#2 /path/to/app/Console/cake.php(48): ShellDispatcher::run(NULL)
#3 {main}
```

One thing I have to mention is that my CakePHP installation is formed by several apps that load **one same core library**, which is in a different folder than the apps themselves. The apps work perfectly fine, it's just this cron script I can get to work. In the **cake.php inside the Console folder of the app** I've updated the following line to reflect that too (before doing this I was getting a different error I figure because the core Console files weren't found):

```
//$install = $root . DS . 'lib';
$install = '/path/to/libs/cakephp-2.10.18';
```

I've looked at all the paths of libraries being loaded, updated the php.ini variables and system PATH as suggested in the linked solutions and CakePHP's own [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) but I still can't get this to work.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. **Again, if I run the same script from the command line it works fine, it's when I call it from cron that I have the issue**. *The shell script is located inside the Console/Command folder of the app.*

All this is in a LAMP server using CakePHP 2.10.18.

Answer (score 0):

You may call the shell function first in controller and then call controller function in cron.

Comment: Yeah but the whole point of using shells is to avoid doing that... I could put the logic that I have in the shell script in the controller and completely forget about shells, but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish...